# How to create a long running service in oreo

Tags: java, android

I am making a battery alarm app in this app  I want to ring the sound when battery is full for that I need to use service but in Oreo I can not run my service for long time so please tell me how can I run my service in Oreo for long time.i have also used **startForgroundService** with notification but this also not work in Oreo.my minimum SDK version is 15 and target is 27
Please help me.
Thanks...

Comment: You don't need a service. Schedule an alarm to check the battery level at intervals of a few minutes.

Comment: What for you need a long service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create long-running service in oreo. Services will be killed when the phone goes into sleep mode.

You can u `JobScheduler` for that.

```
ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
        //builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); // require unmetered network
        //builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
        //builder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

set your requirement as `builder.setRequiresCharging(true);` 
and detect your battery level there.

Source: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler